# Set content in Multi-valued text field

Tags: event-system, tom.net

I have a field called customerType in the Metadata of a Schema. It is a **multi-valued text field**.
I would like to update the Component using Event System to set the Metadata of this field. So far I am able to place single value into this field using the code snippet placed below.

```
    foreach (ItemField field in metadataFields)
    {
       if (field.Name.Equals("customerType"))
       {     
           ((TextField)field).Value = "Test1";
       }
    }
```

Could you please let us know how to place multiple values in this multi valued text field. For instance, I would like to have "Test1" and "Test2" into this field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.Values` property instead of `.Value`
.Values property is always available if field is multi-value.

You can have something like this:

```
         foreach (ItemField field in metadataFields)
                {
                    if (field.Name.Equals("customerType"))
                    {
                        IList<string> values = ((TextField)field).Values;
                        foreach (string value in values)
                        {
                            //do something
                        }

                    }
                }
```

You can also see it in TOM.NET API:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marko. The Values property seems to be read-only, so it may not be helpful in setting up a value in textbox corresponding to that field.

Comment: Values is indeed read only, but you can add or remove items from this collection, so you can do something like field.Values.Add("data");

Comment: Yes, @Harald is correct.